# Show that $W_1$ is a subset of $W_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

$\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a set of lineraly independent vectors that are from $R^5 $.

Let $W_1=span(\{v_1,v_2,v_3\})$ and $W_2=span(\{2v_1+3v_2+v_3,v_1-v_2-2v_3,2v_1+v_2-v_3\})$

Is $W_1$ a subset of $W_2$?

My attempt:

Take a vector $ a \in W_1$. We can write this vector as $a=k_1v_1+k_2v_2+k_3v_3$. If it is also in $W_2$, then we can show that it can be written as $a=l_1w_1+l_2w_2+l_3w_3=(2l_1+l_2+2l_3)v_1+(3l_1-l_2+l_3)v_2+(l_1-2l_2-l_3)v_3$.

Then, $(2l_1+l_2+2l_3)=k_1, (3l_1-l_2+l_3)=k_2, (l_1-2l_2-l_3)=k_3$

From this part what should I do? When I solve the linear system:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 2 &k_1\\
3 & -1 & 1 &k_2\\
1 & -2 & -1 & k_3
\end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 &k_1+k_3-k_2\\
0 & 5 & 4 &k_2-3k_3\\
1 & -2 & -1 & k_3
\end{bmatrix}$

Because of the first row, there is no solution? What should I get from this solution?

Comment: No, because there will be $k_1$, $k_2$ and $k_3$ such that $k_1+k_3-k_2=0$. If that system had no solution for any $k_1$, $k_2$ and $k_3$, it would mean that no vector in $W_1$ is in $W_2$, but clearly $2v_1+3v_2+v_3$ is in both $W_1$ and $W_2$ (also note that for $(k_1,k_2,k_3)=(2,3,1)$ we have $2+1-3=0$ so the system isn't inconsistent). But you can choose specific $k_1$, $k_2$ and $k_3$ such that $k_1+k_3-k_2\neq 0$, for example $(k_1,k_2,k_3)=(1,0,0)$. This implies that $v_1\notin W_2$.

Comment: (*From comment on deleted answer below*) "*We haven't learned about determinants yet, is there another way of stating that?*"  [The Invertible Matrix Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleMatrixTheorem.html) gives a few dozen conditions all of which are equivalent to a matrix being invertible.  Over the first semester or two of a Linear Algebra course, you will be asked to prove most of these equivalences in your exercises or have them proved for you by the book or in lecture.

Comment: @RandyMarsh so can we say that $W_1$ is not a subset of $W_2$ because if the vector from $W_1$ can be written as $k_1v_1+k_2v_2+k_3v_3$ but $k_1+k_3 \neq k_2$ then it cannot be in $W_2$

Comment: Yes, exactly. To show that $W_1\nsubseteq W_2$ you only need one vector that is in $W_1$ but not in $W_2$, however you have also proven that there are infinitely many vectors that are in $W_1$ but not in $W_2$.